# how to draw route lines on imageview in android (indoor Positioning)

Tags: android, git, indoor-positioning-system

I have done wifi based indoor positioning ([my Git Project](https://github.com/mmusaab/indoor-position-tracker)), now i stuck making it more realistic,  i have to draw lines on map to redirect user to specific point.

i have all `(x,y)` points, i want pixel distance and near far algorithms to reach at some point from specific point.

in other words i want to add indoor navigation in my project, is there any kind of help?? i ll be very thankful.